# Real-time .NET app monitoring without client polling

Tags: asp.net, .net, signalr, monitoring, polling

We're building a real-time Web-based monitoring system for .NET applications (ASP.NET and Windows executable). Those applications can start a long-running operations and statistics are displayed in real-time on Web page.

For ASP.NET ones we found SignalR a perfect solution: Long running operation (even caused by simple WebForms form postback) periodically call JS client-side functions via SignalR RPC to update monitoring page. But we hit 2 caveats:

1. In ASP.NET we need to monitor several different apps located in several different virtual directories. How do we push data from those different apps onto a single HTML monitoring page?
2. Another app is a .NET Windows console executable that runs periodically on a schedule. How do we push its run-time statistics to the same monitoring HTML page? One thing comes to mind - have EXE store temporary statistics in a DB and have client pull same data from the DB, but we'd like to avoid polling. Another - periodically at a given intervals the EXE would call the WebApp, passing the data - and WebApp would pass it to client via the same SignalR call. But are there better ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very new to SignalR, didn't realize it has multiple clients for different platforms. We will go with SignalR .NET client for all the apps - they will all talk to main SignalR hub directly invoking server-side methods, which in turn update monitoring page.

Comment: Would it be more beneficial to to run Hub as a Windows service and have all monitored apps invoke its methods and in turn have it invoke methods of the monitoring app  to display data? Or having monitoring app itself host a hub which all the other apps will call is enough?

Answer (score 0):

One architecture that I've used is a small monitoring collection service, with embedded monitoring clients in every monitored application, Asp.net, Windows desktop app, console app, Windows service, or otherwise.

The collection service is always running. A webapp then connects directly to the service and requests the state of all monitored apps.

Monitored apps run some small embedded client that feeds back application-specific metrics to the monitoring service. The client can either provide data on events or timers, or the monitoring service an ask for it on a timer itself.

With this, we have a unified monitoring architecture - everything that runs just talks to the monitoring service to send updates, and the health viewer clients just ask the service for data using a unified protocol.

It's basically the Application Server pattern applied to monitoring, and takes a couple cues from the design of SNMP.

Comment: Looks like a real good approach and we probably eventually implement it. Meanwhile we will probably go with SignalR on console apps as well.